# Determine whether a COM is a In-Proc or LocalServer

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I got an application that use a COM library, just wondering how can I know whether that application use that COM library as a LocalServer or In-Proc?

I looked at the code being constructed in this way:

```
DATCOMLib::ITEmulationPtr pTE(__uuidof(DATCOMLib::TEmulation));
```

Comment: Not being able to find out with any api function is core to the way COM is designed.  You can always find out with Taskmgr.exe

Comment: And don't forget about COM surrogating: the library may be in-proc but hosted by special process, not yours. See the following as a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695225(v=vs.85).aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/12/9413816.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It depends partly on what execution context you supply when you create your object - see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693716(v=vs.85).aspx

You can look up the class id for your component in the registry and check whether it has a LocalServer sub-key. So in your case you would look for:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID of DATACOMLib::TEmulation}\LocalServer
```

If it is an In Proc COM component it will instead have the following key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{CLSID of DATACOMLib::TEmulation}\InProcServer32
```

Check this documentation for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908849.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It can be find out using multiple ways

1. From looking at the code - check what is the class context passed when calling "**CreateInstance**" or "**CoCreateInstance**" - (CLSCTX_INPROC_XXXX then it is inproc server means it is DLL which will be loaded into calling applications process address space. CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER - then it is COM server running as a separate process. There are some #defines which combines one or more flags. Just google it)

   `ITEmulationPtr.CreateInstance(uuid(TEmulation), 0, CLSCTX_XXX)`
2. If you have access to machine on which COM component is installed then you can follow steps given by Peter in above answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Run your app and make sure it loads the COM object (the code reached the part shown in your question)
2. Open process explorer ( get it from Microsoft if you don't already have it)
3. Search for the dll name using process explorer if it is inside your exe then it is in-proc otherwise it is not.